# junit - how to make a real test instead of mocking (altering the results)

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I have the following test case i've written but im a little confused if this is a good test.  because from what i can tell i am altering the real outcome when i mock with userDataMock.  So really i have already changed the final result to be "expected". So when i do the real test the only outcome it can be is "expected" because i've already mocked it to be that with `Mockito.when(userDataMock.doStandardLogin(loginInfoMock)).thenReturn(expected);`
I've seen developers do this before, but i'd like a real test. What am i doing wrong or not thinking of ?

```
public class DoStandardLoginUsecaseTest {

  private DoStandardLoginUsecase target;
  private MyApplication contextMock;

  @Before
  public void beforeEach() {
      contextMock = Mockito.mock(MyApplication.class);
      // Note that you need to mock the getPresenterComponent
      // but I don't know what it returns.
      target = new DoStandardLoginUsecase(contextMock);
  }

  @Test
  public void buildUseCaseObservable() {
       UserDataRepository userDataMock = Mockito.mock(UserDataRepository.class);
       StandardLoginInfo loginInfoMock = Mockito.mock(StandardLoginInfo.class);
       target.mUserDataRepo = userDataMock;
       target.setLoginInfo(loginInfoMock);

       Observable<Login> expected = // create your expected test data however you like...
       Mockito.when(userDataMock.doStandardLogin(loginInfoMock)).thenReturn(expected);
       Observable<Login> actual = target.buildUseCaseObservable();

       Assert.areSame(actual, expected);
  }
```

}

update: here is the actual class that i am targeting the test on:

DoStandardLoginUsecase.java:

```
public class DoStandardLoginUsecase extends BaseUseCase {

@Inject
UserDataRepository mUserDataRepo;

private StandardLoginInfo loginInfo;

@Inject
public DoStandardLoginUsecase(UserDataRepository userDataRepository) {
mUserDataRepo = userDataRepository;
}

@Override
public Observable<Login> buildUseCaseObservable() {
    return mUserDataRepo.doStandardLogin(loginInfo);
}

public void setLoginInfo(StandardLoginInfo loginInfo) {
    this.loginInfo = loginInfo;
}
```

}

Comment: What is the code / behavior you are testing? If you don't mock that out, you're good. If you don't even execute the code under test, you've screwed up. The point of mocking is to control the inputs, and that is totally fine. You couldn't test certain conditions without it.

Comment: I am trying to test a user logging in and that i get back a token.  so in a class called DoStandardLoginUsecase i make the call to UserDataRepository to acutally do a retrofit call.  So i actually would rather do a real test here and get a real result.

Comment: Do you mind sharing the method that is under test?  Hard to judge the quality of the test without it.

Comment: i updated my question. The the buildUseCaseObservable will actually return a Observable i can subscribe to to trigger the login rest call.

Comment: You either do integration test or unit test. With unit test you use mocks and only test `DoStandardLoginUsecase` code. If you need to get actual token from `mUserDataRepo` then it will be integration test.

Comment: i see what you mean @tsolakp good point.  and in the integration tests can those be in androidTest folder ? or what i mean is can they be considered functional tests ?

Comment: You can. I am not familiar with Android setup but it is totally fine to put test supporting files along with testing code in Maven for example. You just need to make sure your test will not fail anywhere and anytime it is build and run.

Comment: @j2emanue https://developer.android.com/training/testing/start/index.html#config-instrumented-tests This might help in configuring the tests appropriately in their destined destined folders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very healthy thought, that's true - when you mock everything out you eventually test your test. Unfortunately today mocking is a very common practice that's mostly misused. Instead of mocking you could write different kinds of tests:

- Unit tests would check the classes in isolation. For this to be possible without mocking you need to follow good old OOP and rich model in particular.
- Component (a.k.a. integration) tests - these could initialize a part of your app and check a clusters of classes. You can initialize spring contexts with in-memory DB for instance.
- System tests are run against fully deployed app. If it's a UI, these could be Selenium tests. If this is a REST API, these could be RestAssured tests.

This is called a [Test Pyramid](http://qala.io/blog/test-pyramid.html). But sometimes you still want to mock. This usually happens on the boundaries of the system. E.g. you get some data from the external site and parse out the results. To check parsing you don't really need a connection to the external site - you can mock the part that gets the data. This allows you to write very fast and simple tests.